# Copying Excel worksheets with NPOI CopySheet; copy is always blank

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I'm trying to create an application that will merge the excel spreadsheets in a given directory into a single, tabbed Excel workbook. I only have access to VS Community 2015, so VSTO is out of the question; I'm using Interop and NPOI 2.1.3.1 instead.

Here's my code:

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
XSSFWorkbook test = new XSSFWorkbook();

try
{
    string fPath = files[0];
    FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(fPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    XSSFWorkbook myBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs2);
    test.CreateSheet(myBook.GetSheetName(0));
    var sheet1 = myBook.GetSheetAt(0).CopySheet(test.GetSheetName(0));

    test.Write(new FileStream("testFile.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
}
catch {  }
```

I'm not trying to do anything fancy, here, just get the first file returned by the GetFiles function, copy everything on the first worksheet, and create a new worksheet in new workbook "test" with what was copied. I know the source file is being found, because sheet1 of the output file "testFile.xlsx" is getting the unique sheet name of the source worksheet -- it isn't "Sheet1". However, the rest of the sheet comes up blank, and I don't know why.

I'm using this against Excel 2016, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Why are you using both Interop and NPOI?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the two different solutions: one for Interop (xlsx file format) and the other for NPOI (xls file format). These solutions get the excel files in a folder, read the excel files and copy the sheets to a new excel file.

Using Interop.Excel:

```
// using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Application app = new Application();
app.Visible = false;
app.DisplayAlerts = false;

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp\excel");

foreach (string file in files)
{
    app.Workbooks.Add(file);
}

for (int i = 2; i <= app.Workbooks.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets.Count; j++)
    {
        Worksheet ws = app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets[j];
        ws.Copy(app.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1]);
    }
}

app.Workbooks[1].SaveCopyAs(@"c:\temp\excel\output\testFile.xlsx");
app.Quit();
```

Using NPOI:

```
// using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;

string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp\excel");
HSSFWorkbook workbookMerged = new HSSFWorkbook();

foreach (string file in files)
{
    HSSFWorkbook workbook;

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

        for (int i = 0; i < workbook.NumberOfSheets; i++)
        {
            ((HSSFSheet)workbook.GetSheetAt(i)).CopyTo(workbookMerged, workbook.GetSheetName(i), true, true);
        }
    }
}

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\excel\output\testFile.xls", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
{
    workbookMerged.Write(fs);
}
```

Note that for the NPOI solution, I converted my `xlsx` files to `xls` to use HSSF instead of XSSF, as there's not `CopyTo` method available for `XSSFSheet`. This method is only available for `HSSFSheet`, as of the latest NPOI version 2.3.0.

Comment: @krizix. Can I use your solution to convert xls to xlsx? Or I am overlooking the  obvious?

Comment: That was not the purpose of my answer. It was to copy a sheet. I converted the Excel file using Excel, not by coding. Maybe you can find an answer with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29522173/1351076). @Mark